# cv::VideoCapture decoding with GStreamer

Tags: c++, opencv, gstreamer

I'm trying to decode a H264 video using the hardware decoder built in the Intel graphics card in Windows. I'm coding that with OpenCV's GStreamer option. I got it working by using the follow GStreamer command line utility through the following pipeline command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=temp.mp4 ! qtdemux ! d3d11h264dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

However, when I put it in the code with OpenCV, The first frame I receive is an empty frame. The code sample is as below:

```
cv::VideoCapture videoCap;
char* sCmd = "filesrc location=temp.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! d3d11h264dec ! videoconvert ! appsink sync=false";
if (!videoCap.open(sCmd, cv::CAP_GSTREAMER))
    return;

if (videoCap.isOpened()) {
    cv::Mat cvTemp;

    // read first frame
    videoCap.set(cv::CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO, 0);
    videoCap.read(cvTemp);

   if (cvTemp.empty())
      return;

.......
.......
```

The video capture object is opened fine. But, the frame read out, cvTemp, is empty. The OpenCV is built with GStreamer enabled under VS2019 C++, and I can perform hardware encoding using Intel's encoder, qsvh264enc. Could anybody point out what I'm missing here?

Eric

Comment: it doesnt give any warning in the console during streaming ?

Comment: Try commenting out the line setting CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO. Gstreamer backend uses GST_FORMAT_PERCENT that is not supported by most elements and deprecated.

Comment: Check the return value of videoCap.read. if it is true just continue and skip the empty frame.

Comment: SeB, commenting out the line setting CAP_PROP_POS_AVI_RATIO solves my problem!! Never thought that is the thing! There is an another call: videoCap.get(cv::CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT) fails all the time. I guess GStreamer does not like CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT either. Is there a way to get the frame count so I can set my slider to show the progress? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how much duration is reliable from opencv gstreamer backend. Do you see warnings about this when the pipeline starts ? Sorry I'm unable to help more about this, I'm mostly using live sources. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/videoio/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp

Comment: Maybe if can you issue a command before, you would get details of your video with `gst-discoverer-1.0 -v temp.mp4`.